# Difference between Personal Tabs and Teams Tabs in Microsoft Teams. What are the Pros and Cons of each tabs?

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, microsoft-graph-teams

Difference between Personal Tabs and Teams Tabs in Microsoft Teams. What are the Pros and Cons of each tabs ?

Comment: A Teams tab delivers content to channels and group chats, and are a great way to create collaborative spaces around dedicated web-based content. Personal tabs, along with personally-scoped bots, are part of personal apps and are scoped to a single user.